# Bash - What is the best way to save the value of a quantity after the script has terminated?

Tags: bash

I am attempting to write a script that changes my desktop wallpaper to the next picture in my `~\Picture\Wallpapers` directory. I have already created a script, `change_wallpaper`, which can change my desktop background to any given picture.

My plan was to list all the pictures in `~\Picture\Wallpapers` as an array, find the index `i` of the current wallpaper, and apply `change_wallpaper` to the `i+1` element of the array of pictures. My only issue is finding a way to story the index of the current wallpaper. I could create a file which contains this value, but it seems really inelegant to just have a text file with the number 12, for example, saved somewhere in my home directory.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use a file.  Files are central concepts in UNIX.  As an analogy, your integer is like any daemon's PID file.  As a side benefit, your wall paper index will survive reboot.

Comment: If you have a stable sort-order for the files in the directory you could just use a symlink to the current file and then get the next file and update the link.

Comment: @EtanReisner Good thought.  Could also have two symlinks: current and next, then just move next to current and choose a suitable next.

Comment: If you are writing the script that will run in background continuously (for changing image after specific time), you can use a variable in the bash script, else you will have to use file since bash don't have any static variable.

Comment: @bishop Doesn't change much that way, but sure. You still have to figure out the next file somehow. You just change when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the general consensus of using a file to store the index of the current wallpaper.  A slightly more elegant way would be to put a "." (dot) in front of the file name to keep it hidden in the directory where your script is located.  Something like:

```
admin@myHost:/home/admin$ ls -la
total 6200
drwxrwxr-x    4 admin    admin          4096 Jul 02 15:41 .
drwxr-xr-x   71 bin      bin            4096 Jun 29 12:43 ..
-rw-------    1 admin    admin          3939 Jun 29 16:02 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 admin    admin            21 Nov 04 2014  .bashrc
-rwxr-x--x    1 admin    admin           259 Oct 13 2014  .profile
-rw-------    1 admin    admin          3939 Jun 29 16:02 .wallpaper_index
-rw-------    1 admin    admin          3939 Jun 29 16:02 change_wallpaper
```

There are countless linux and unix applications that do this.